# Can't get hamburger menu to animate on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, sass

I targeted the SVG rect using :nth-chid(1), 2 and 3 and made a -> that I'm trying to trigger on click. Don't know what I'm doing wrong here. Any Help would be great thank you!

```js
(function() {
  var burger;

  buger = document.getElementById('burger');

  burger.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('you cliked the burger');
    return burger.classList.toggle('st0-active');
  });

}).call(this);
```

```css
body {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.st0-active:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(27deg) translate(23px, -51px);
          transform: rotate(27deg) translate(23px, -51px);
  fill: #000;
}
.st0-active:nth-child(2) {
  fill: #000;
}
.st0-active:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-21deg) translate(-48px, 15px);
          transform: rotate(-21deg) translate(-48px, 15px);
  fill: #000;
}
```

```html
<body>
<svg class="mo-icon__svg" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 200 200" style="enable-background:new 0 0 200 200;" xml:space="preserve" id="burger">
<g id="icon_x5F_hamburger">
 <rect x="0.11206" y="46.3329" class="st0" width="200" height="8"/>
 <rect x="0.11206" y="96.22083" class="st0" width="200" height="8"/>
 <rect x="0.11206" y="146.10876" class="st0" width="200" height="8"/>
</g>
</svg>
  
</body>
```

Here is a picture of my designed end goal
[image]

Which is the reason I'm using CSS Transforms and targeting the rect using nth-child Here is a link to the codepen that I'm currently working on 
[enter link description here](https://codepen.io/Brushel/pen/ZXXqZb?editors=1111)

Comment: `buger` => `burger`

Comment: What is that symbol? Please replace with text

Comment: @JeanValjean That symbol is a hamburger, as in hamburger menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
(function() {
  var burger;

  burger = document.getElementById('burger');

  burger.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('you cliked the burger');
    return burger.classList.toggle('st0-active');
  });

}).call(this);
```

```css
body {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#burger > g > rect{
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.st0-active > g > rect:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(27deg) translate(23px, -51px);
      transform: rotate(27deg) translate(23px, -51px);
  fill: #000;
}
.st0-active > g > rect:nth-child(2) {
  fill: #000;
}
.st0-active > g > rect:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-21deg) translate(-48px, 15px);
      transform: rotate(-21deg) translate(-48px, 15px);
  fill: #000;
}
```

```html
<body>
<svg class="mo-icon__svg" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 200 200" style="enable-background:new 0 0 200 200;" xml:space="preserve" id="burger">
<g id="icon_x5F_hamburger">
 <rect x="0.11206" y="46.3329" class="st0" width="200" height="8"/>
 <rect x="0.11206" y="96.22083" class="st0" width="200" height="8"/>
 <rect x="0.11206" y="146.10876" class="st0" width="200" height="8"/>
</g>
</svg>
  
</body>
```

Try to add this code.

```
#burger{
  transition: transform 1s;
}
```

Additionally

**CSS3 transitions allows you to change property values smoothly (from one value to another), over a given duration.**

Comment: Please do not post code-only answers; they are not helpful.

Comment: Thank you! But what I'm trying to accomplish is to have the hamburger menu turn into an arrow like this ->

Comment: @ThomasBrushel wait a minutes.

Comment: @YoungKyunJin Thank you!! This helped me a lot!!

Comment: @ThomasBrushel It's my pleasure :)